# C++ Dynamic Constructor

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error:

> no operator "[]" matches these operands

For the line:

```
cout << A[j].display(n)
```

But when I take out the `[j]`,  I'm getting the error:

> class "list" has no member "display"

Here is my code:

```
class list
{
protected:
    int *p; // pointer to a list
    int size; // dimension
public:
    list(int x)
    {
        size = x;
        p = new int[size]; 
    }
    void get(int i, int val)
    {
        p[i] = val;
    }
};

class dlist : public list
{
public:
    int display(int i)
    {
        return p[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter elements in a row\n";
    cin >> n;

    list A(n);

    int j, val;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> val;
        A.get(j, val);
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "List of elements are :\n";
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cout << A[j].display(j) << "\t"; 
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: `A` is not an array nor have you overloaded the `[]` operator. And, please format your code.

Comment: Also, `A` is a `list` object, not a `dlist` object so it has no `display` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `list` indeed has no member function `display`. It is the class `dlist` declared like

```
class dlist : public list
//...
```

has such a member function. However the object `A` was defined in main like an object of class `list`

```
list A(n);
```

Moreover you can not create an object of the type `dlist` because you have to define explicitly a constructor of the type.

If you want to use polymorphism then introduce virtual functions making for example the member function `display`  like virtual.

Also this syntax

```
cout << A[j].display(j) << "\t";
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is incorrect because the object `A` is a scalar object. It is not an array of objects and the class has no overloaded `operator []`.

You should start by defining explicitly a virtual destructor (otherwise there can be a memory leak in your program)  that delete dynamically allocated memory in the constructor with parameter, copy constructor and the copy assignment operator in the class list. Then you can define the subscript operator and so on.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks. It seems I have updated the post correctly.:)